# how can i return something and break the loop same time in python

Tags: python, return, break

```
while True:
    if abs(func_value) < epsilon:
        return (x_0, itNum)
    if abs(func_value) < epsilon:
        break

    else:
        assert deriv_value != 0
        x_0 = x_0 - (func_value / deriv_value)
        itNum += 1
```

I do not want to write twice the condition. Is there another way to write this more appropriate?

i am so sorry guys,,

actually it continues with else statement that updates the func_value . i have just fixed

Comment: The return will already break the loop.  It will end the whole function.

Comment: When u say return x, it means you breaking the loop and returning the value... so no need of break statement..

Comment: Is your `abs(func_value) < epsilon` condition failing somehow? It's not at all possible for a function to continue if `return` was called. Also you're never changing the value of `func_value` or `epsilon` that I can see, so you're never going to break out of the loop.

Answer (score 7):

The `return` command immediately exits whatever function you're in, so if you're returning, there is no need to break out of a `while` loop. You've already broken out of it, along with that entire function.